# Attach to running windows process

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, profiling, internals

please adisve on below:

1) What is the lightest way to attach to running native windows application process, get list of threads and see what DDLs are used?

2) What is the lightest way to attach to running .NET application process, get list of threads and see what DDLs are used?

Regards,
Ron

Comment: I take it you mean DLL, not DDL, right?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Tool Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837(v=vs.85).aspx) which make it easier for you to obtain information about currently executing applications.

- [Thread Walking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686780(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Module Walking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684236(v=vs.85).aspx)

.Net [example](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.html) or [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot++%5B.net%5D) to find more info.

---

The [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t15zda.aspx) namespace provides classes that allow you to interact with system processes, event logs, and performance counters.

- [ProcessThreadCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthreadcollection.aspx) class provides a strongly typed collection of ProcessThread objects.
- [ProcessModuleCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodulecollection.aspx) class provides a strongly typed collection of ProcessModule objects.

[search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=System.Diagnostics++%5B.net%5D) to find more

Comment: Thank you for response. It seems like first 50% of the question - what threads are used. So, what is the proper way to see what DDLs are being used by the thread?

Comment: The process is a container for resources including DLLs, which are mapped into the virtual address space of the process. Any process thread has access to the entire address space and any DLLs within it.

Comment: Thank you. I should clarify my question on DLLs - is there is a way to see what DLLs are used by thread "at the moment", i.e. actively called from a thread.

Comment: You need obtains a stack trace for a thread and examine which module it currently uses.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Visual Studio? If so, you can attach VS to any running process using the Debug | Attach To Process menu items. You can then break into the process and start examining stacks, threads, modules, etc.

If you want to delve deeper, you could download the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx) and install the Debugging tools. This will give you KD and WinDBG - a console debugger and slightly more friendly multi-pane MDI-style debugging app respectively. Using these tools you can access to most of the core debugging infrastructure built into Windows.

**However**, note that this is **not** for the feint of heart and will require considerable time and effort to master. To really become a debugging guru, you'll also need to deeply understand the architecture of the kernel & OS and many core OS data structures.

Thus you might find the following books useful:

For .NET:

- [Debugging Applications for .NET and Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615365)
- [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)

For Windows and/or .NET:

- [Windows Internals 6th edition vol. 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648735)
- [Windows Internals 6th edition vol. 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735665877)

For Advanced Windows internals debugging

- [Inside Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735662789)
- [Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460)

Enjoy! :)